# How to validate ObjectId query param in FastAPI

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

I have an endpoint that recibe and id field used to get data from MongoDB's _id:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from bson import ObjectId

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/get-data")
async def get_strategies(order_id: ObjectId):
    return Manager().get_data(order_id)
```

I want validate if `order_id` is valid as `ObjectId`, if later, inside the function, `order_id` is a `str` or `ObjectId` it doesn't matter.

How can I do this?
Thanks for help!

Comment: What does your requesting ObjectId look like? Do you want to validate that it conforms to what you'd expect a MongoDB objectId to look like, or do you want to resolve whether it's a valid `order_id` as well? (the latter is perfectly reasonable and will give you very composable view functions by having a `order: Depends(order_from_param_order_id)` for example)

Comment: @MatsLindh thansks for answer.
`ObjectId` is class imported from `bson` package, I think is the same class that mongodb use for `_id` field ( primary key for each document ).
You approach of `order: Depends(order_from_param_order_id)` look fine too, I will try it

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd get from a binary representation to the ObjectId _through a JSON-body/url-parameter, so it would depend on how what kind of a value you'd want to submit. You can use a dependency to convert any input string to an ObjectId if possible.

Comment: @MatsLindh Maybe I explained myself wrong, in this case I apologize. English is not my first language.

I leave below the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I found this validator: `Query`, this is used to validate http GET parameters.
Also there is this validator: `Path` to validate path parameters, below I left and example:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Path, Query
from bson import ObjectId

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/get-data")
async def get_strategies(order_id: str = Query(..., regex=r"^[0-9a-f]{24}$")):
    return Manager().get_data(order_id)


@router.get("/get-data/{order_id}")
async def get_strategies(order_id: str = Path(..., regex=r"^[0-9a-f]{24}$")):
    return Manager().get_data(order_id)
```

- The `...` inside Query and Path is to indicate parameter is required.
- ObjectId is an hexadecimal string with 24 characters. that is mached with the regex